# .NET application closes without error on using library methods

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, poco-libraries

I have a C++ DLL Library. I'm testing the DLL with a C# Project with NET Framework 4.0. In the C++ DLL I'm using some libraries, like POCO, Boost, ODBC, SQLite, SOCI...

It was doing great until I decided to replace the SOCI interface with the POCO one to reduce the number of libraries loaded in the library.

I compiled the PocoData, PocoDataODBC and added them, together with the headers, into the project. The project compiles OK, creates the DLL, and the DLL passes the **Dependency Walker** tests.

But something strange happens when using the DLL from the .NET Project. The app just closes when executing the DLL methods that contains the `Poco::Data` part to connect with the database.

There is no exception or error thrown. Not even "application just crashed" from windows. It just stop running and the Visual Studio returns to normal just like if it ended correctly.

I isolated the error and it's enought with **any** use or call inside the PocoData library to do this error. I can use the library until it tries to use a method that has any call to this. For example:

```
Session session("ODBC", conn);
```

Or even this alone:

```
Poco::Data::RecordSet rs();
```

So every time the C# calls a method that contains anything from the `Poco::Data` in the DLL it fails.

Any idea what can be happening?

---

Windows events log something when the app makes the error, I don't know if it's relevant. It raises two events, the first one is a system hour change between same value (strange), type: `Kernel-General`.

The second one (about 10 seconds later) is `Service Control Manager` level `Information`:

> Service Windows Error Reporting Service entered in running state.

Comment: Have you checked the bitness of the native DLLs matches the bitness of the .NET process? (Though admittedly I'd expect this to surface as a BadImageFormatException).  Another might be related to side-by-side assemblies, that can happen with the SQL Server SMI DLLs.  If that's the problem, that can be fixed by adding this setting to the `.config` file:

    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>

Comment: Have you checked to see if anything is logged in the windows event viewer?

Comment: You could also try adding an unhandled exception event and add some logging. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Comment: @CathalMF Unhandled exception catcher does nothing. I added it in the C++ project and in the C# project. No effect. Windows event log has something, but idk if it's relevant. I'm adding it to the question.

Comment: @martin_costello I'm using Poco ODBC to connect to a SQL Server database, but the `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy` has no effect